# A way to release the resource inside ValidationEventHandler

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am validating an xml with an xsd schema.
When ValidationEventHandler callback is triggered I can log if it's an error or a warning but I also want to release the xml under validation and move it from one directory to another. Right now I get "used by another process" exception if I try to do so.

Any idea how I can overcome this? Could throwing an exception from inside the ValidationEventHandler to be caught from outside could work?

Thanks,

Comment: Presumably at this point the document is still being validated? Why not just record the fact there was an error and, when validation is complete, decide what to do based on that?

Comment: Isn't the validation already complete when the ValidationEventHandler is invoked (after it recognized that there are existing warning and/or errors).

Comment: It will be invoked once per warning or error. There might be multiple things.

Comment: If you don't care what the errors are, then you probably could stop reading after the first error. You'd need to provide a [mcve], as we've no idea how you're validating this at present - e.g. what opens the file, when is that closed etc.